# Loop function printing out multiple same outputs instead of just one

Tags: python, loops

I wrote this code for checking uppercase, lowercase, etc. without using functions.
Its working pretty well in regards of detecting different inputs but it prints out an output for every input. Tried to find the mistake but it just worsens the problem.
My code

```
mylist=[]
end=str("!")
a=0
counter=0
while a != end:
    a=input()
    mylist.append(a)
for i in mylist:
    if i in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':
        print("1",end='')
    else:
        print("0",end='')
        
    if i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        print("1",end='')
    else:
        print("0",end='')

    if i in '0123456789"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c':
        print("1", end='')
    else:
        print('0', end='')
        
    for i in mylist:
        counter=counter+1
        
    counter=counter-1
        
    if counter < 7:
        print("0")
    else:
        print("1")
```

For example, if I input a b c d e !, it outputs 0100 five times and 0000 once instead of just 0100 once, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Please explain why 0100 is the correct output.  You have five characters, each of which you classify into each of four categories.  Therefore, you get five lines of four int(Boolean) values.  What are you *trying* to do?

Comment: Looks like you have a nested loop `for i in mylist: ... for i in mylist:`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have separate blocks of multiple `if`s and when only one get satisfied, the values are printed from other `else` blocks.

You should instead consider using `if-elif-else` block as:

```
if i in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':
    print("1",end='')
elif i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    print("1",end='')
elif some more conditions:
    # do something
else:
    print("0",end='')
```

Further, if you just want to print the same stuff in all the blocks you could consider joining all `if` blocks in one as:

```
if i in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' or i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    print("1",end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Break Statement after every condition
So it would exit the loop every time after checking and it won't verify all conditions thereby avoiding multiple printing

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your application is that every character is verified in every if, so one character is tested in three diferrent if statements, so that every character will output three digits (either one or zero). And after that, you made another for inside the main for to check the number of characters on your list. Do that outside the main for loop, I think this is what you want. A suggestion, try to use len(..) instead of looping the entire list just for the size.

What I suggest to you is to take a paper and a pen and to test your code, step by step.